# how to target specific ul in vue?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

on click i want to expand specific ul but it's expanding every ul.i'm not able to target the single ul .

```css
.ul {
  list-style: none;
  right: 25px;
  bottom: 10px;
  height: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cfdada;
}

.landingPage ul.activeClass {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="pageContent" v-for="(item,index) in dataBox[selectedTab]">
                    <span v-for="(e,i) in dataBox[selectedTab][index]">
                        <h4>{{i}}</h4>
                        <ul v-bind:class="{activeClass:isActive}">
                            <li v-for="m in e">{{m.name}}</li>
                        </ul>
                        <span v-if="!isActive" v-on:click="{isActive=!isActive}" class="moreIcon">More..</span>
                    </span>
                </div>
```

Comment: you to do this on `li` not `ul`

Comment: could you please explain?

Comment: you want the li to be active??/

Comment: on more button click only one ul should expand .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isActive` should be set to every object `e`, you should change your code like this:

```js
computed: {
  activeDataBox () {
    return this.dataBox.map(e => {
      e.isActive = false
      return e
    })
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="pageContent" v-for="(item,index) in activeDataBox[selectedTab]">
  <span v-for="(e,i) in activeDataBox[selectedTab][index]">
    <h4>{{i}}</h4>
    <ul v-bind:class="{activeClass:e.isActive}">
      <li v-for="m in e">{{m.name}}</li>
    </ul>
    <span v-if="!e.isActive" v-on:click="{e.isActive=!e.isActive}" class="moreIcon">More..</span>
  </span>
</div>
```